# Метод __construct с неопределенным количеством аргументов

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Есть таблица `users` в базе данных, задача: сделать модель (MVC) с возможностью выборки определенных полей таблицы.

```
users.php

class Users 
{
    private $id       = null;

    private $login    = null;
    private $password = null;

    public function __construct($login, $password)
    {
         $this->login       = $login;
         $this->password    = $password;
    }

    // All Setters && Getters for all cells of db
    // a.g public function SetLogin; public function GetLogin

    static public function getInstance($id)  
    {
         $row = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '{$id}' ";
         if($row){
              $obj = new Users($row['login'], $row['password']);
              $obj->setId($row['id']);
              return $obj;
         }
    }
}
```

По условию таблица `users` имеет много ячеек, и не всегда нужно делать выборку записи со всеми ячейками, иными словами запрос в `getInstance` нужно сделать с определенными ячейками, например `(SELECT login FROM users)`; Как в таком случае сделать вызов объекта, ведь конструктору нужны все ячейки, в качестве аргументов?

Как вариант можно в конструктор передавать массив, и в конструкторе для каждого свойства проверять значение в массиве.

```
$this->password = isset($array['password']) ? $array['password'] : null;
```

Но есть ли более лаконичный вариант?

Comment: Используйте поля. Конструктор тут не нужен. А вообще - пересядьте на любую ORM-ку - необходимость в подобных классах сразу отпадёт. У вас сейчас не модель то, а простите за выражение, кусок индусского кода.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с PHP 5.6 доступен новый синтаксис для функций с произвольным количеством аргументов. В принципе для вашей задачи можно использовать его

```
class Users
{
  private $id       = null;

  private $login    = null;
  private $password = null;

  public function __construct(...$fields)
  {
    $this->login       = $fields[0];
    $this->password    = $fields[1];
  }
  ...
}
$user = new Users('hello', 'world');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($user);
```

Однако, в этом случае вы зависите от порядка следования аргументов при создании объекта. Поэтому ваш вариант с использованием одного аргумента-массива является самым гибким. Массив можно сделать ассоциативным, в этом случае будет не важен порядок следования элементов в массиве.

```
class Users
{
  private $id       = null;

  private $login    = null;
  private $password = null;

  public function __construct($fields)
  {
    foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
      $this->$key       = $value;
    }
  }
  // ...
}
$user = new Users(['login' => 'hello', 'password' => 'world']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($user);
```

Единственное, лучше автоматизировать присвоение переменных в цикле, как показано выше (при необходимости можно поставить проверку на допустимое название элемента массива, например, использую `in_array()`, чтобы исключить создание переменных объекта с произвольным именем).